# How to check valid allocation

Tags: c++

The code below is verifying if the allocation is correctly done using if(m_buf).
(The code is from some video tutorial)

```
char *m_buf;

void String::_copy(const char* lpsz){
    if (lpsz != 0){
        int len = MyCString::strlen(lpsz);
        m_buf = new char[len + 1];
        if (m_buf)
            MyCString::strcpy(m_buf, lpsz);
    }
}
```

I wander about two things.
First, Is it really necessary code?
Second, Is it really checking whether `new char[len+1]` is successfully done.
It's just checking if something in char pointer can be true. I know c-string pointer only have first memory address of string but shouldn't it be valid about all string memory addresses? What I'm thinking is since operator new already has code throwing exception i guess, why don't they use try catch?

Let's say you have dynamically allocated object and if you want to check allocation is successfully done. What would you do? and do you think I should do this every time when I make an object?

Comment: `new` throws an exception if it fails, so this check is redundant.

Comment: "shouldn't it be valid about all string memory addresses" shows some basic lack of understanding IMO. A pointer is only a single value, which tells you the **start address** of some memory block. There is no sense in checking every address within that block, once you know that its start address is valid (i.e., within the boundaries of your program's memory). Of course, all of this - assuming that the block was correctly allocated.

Comment: BTW: If you're just learning, then it's okay, but be aware that it's not a good idea to roll your own string classes/functions; use `std::string` and you'll never need to worry about memory leaks, `new` and the like.

Comment: yh, Im just learning, and I know string needs only first address and `\0` at the end of string. What im saying is that code is not doing what its trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check is meaningless since it'll throw `std::bad_alloc` when fails.

> In case of failure, the standard library implementation calls the function pointer returned by [`std::get_new_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/get_new_handler) and repeats allocation attempts until new handler does not return or becomes a null pointer, at which time it throws [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).

Unless you're using non-throwing new like `new(std::nothrow) char[len + 1];`, then the check might be meaningful.

> returns a null pointer on failure instead of propagating the exception.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: Some still program C++ with exceptions disabled, e.g. in embedded systems programming. So the checks are necessary if writing for such a context.

Comment: @BitTickler You mean the behavior will change in such a context? (I thought they just use non-throwing new in such situation.) Then this might be the answer to OP's question.

Comment: Yes - often you can tell the compiler whether or not to create code with or without exception support. So it is up to you to decide if you want to write code working in such a scenario.

Comment: so don't even need to check using try catch either?

Comment: Either ``try ... catch ..`` or ``if(nullptr == pbuf) ...`` or if the system uses structured exception handling ``__try ...``. C++ is not as generically portable as people think. If e.g. you want to write something very portable - a library for example, it gets tough. You best do the if checks to prevent other malfunction and make sure that your code still works if callers of your code add try catch statements in their code.

Comment: @PeteChoi If you want, and could do something with the failed situation, then use try-catch. (And checking if it's nullptr when use non-throwing new)

Comment: @PeteChoi non-throwing new looks like `new (std::no_throw) char [len + 1];`; it's not something the compiler or language decide to do arbitrarily - although this answer makes it sound a bit like that.

Comment: @kfsone I was about to looking for this haha :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointless check, unless you work with non-standard compilers. `new` can never return `nullptr`, it can only fail with a [`bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception, in which case the `if`-check is never even reached.

Answer (score 1):

This code is showing very old and obsolete technique.   Early in the C++ standardisation process (early to mid 90s) the (then) draft standard a number of compilers/libraries only supported an operator `new` that returned NULL on an error.   For example, the ARM (a base document for the standardisation effort) did not suggest that operator `new` would throw on failure.,

The requirements for operator new firmed up - and were finalised in the first C++ standard - so operator `new`, by default, would throw an exception on failure which makes the test unnecessary

```
void String::_copy(const char* lpsz
{
    if (lpsz != 0)
    {
         int len = MyCString::strlen(lpsz);
         m_buf = new char[len + 1];
         MyCString::strcpy(m_buf, lpsz);
    }
}
```

but also require the caller to catch and handle the potentially thrown exception (`std::bad_alloc`).

The test is still required if a different form of operator `new` is used.

```
#include <new>

void String::_copy(const char* lpsz
{
    if (lpsz != 0)
    {
         int len = MyCString::strlen(lpsz);
         m_buf = new (std::nothrow) char[len + 1];
         if (m_buf) MyCString::strcpy(m_buf, lpsz);
    }
}
```

Of course, in modern C++, one wouldn't usually bother to write a `String` class.  Use of `std::string` from `<string>` would be preferred.    `std::string`'s default allocator throws exceptions if memory allocation errors occur.

Comment: but if you see the answer of songyuanyao. it says " repeats allocation attempts until new handler does not return or becomes a null pointe" Doesn't it mean I don't need to catch the exception? is there any case i need to catch the `std::bad_alloc`?

Comment: If the new handler does not return, it either means that the repeated attempt at allocation has succeeded, or that an exception is thrown.    You do not need to catch the exception if you are happy for your program to terminate if an exception occurs.   If you want to take ANY recovery action and continue execution (e.g. recover resources, in order to retry the action that caused the exception to be thrown) it is necessary to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The check is not necessary (at least in this form).

An unsuccessful `new` will throw an exception (`std::bad_alloc`). In your code, it will exit the function, so the `if` is not necessary.

There is a `nothrow` variant of new which will return a `nullptr` instead of throwing, but to use that, you need to write it explicitly.